# Setting Default ACL Does Not Work As Expected

Tags: linux, permissions, acl

I am going to work on a web project and therefore have an `www`-folder inside `$HOME`. I want this folder to be owned by `user` while beloning to group `www-data`. I issue:

```
mkdir $HOME/www
chmod g+rxs,u+rwx,o-rwx $HOME/www
chown user.www-data $HOME/www
```

Then `ls -alh | grep www` gives:

```
drwxr-s---  2 user www-data     4,0K Aug 10 17:33 www
```

Furthermore I want default permissions to be set regardless of the permissions of the creating processes. So I do:

```
setfacl -m d:u::rwx,d:g::rx,d:o::- $HOME/www
```

Then `getfacl $HOME/www` gives:

```
# file: www
# owner: user
# group: www-data
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:group::r-x
default:other::---
```

Now I `cd` into the newly created folder an issue:

```
touch testfile
```

And then `ls -alh | grep testfile` gives:

```
-rw-r-----   1 user www-data    0 Aug 10 17:44 testfile
```

As you can see the group `www-data` was inherited due to the `setgid` bit. But the default ACLs from the directory `$HOME/www` were not inherited (as I would have expected). `$HOME` has different default ACLs compared to `$HOME/www` - but I would expect that manually overriding the subdirectories default ACLs works quite straightforward.

I want the subdirectories and files inside of `$HOME/www` to have the default permissions as given above. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files by default do not get execute permissions. Directories do.
Try creating a directory, it should have the expected permissions.
Files should get the expected default permissions minus execute.

Comment: The subdirs have the permissions as expected. Since I do not need the x-bit on regular files I am quite happy with this answer. Thanks.